# Regex Lookahead not working in IE6

Tags: asp.net, regex, internet-explorer-6, password-protection

I have a regex which works fine in all browsers except IE6. From researching IE6 does not support look ahead assertions. Is there anyway I can rewrite the following expression to be cross browser?

Password must be between 8 and 20 characters and contain at least 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter and 1 number

I am using .Net and regular expression validators.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}$
```

Comment: Can't we just let IE 6 die? :-)

Comment: I wish but its a company requirement. The validation alert pops up every time, even if the condition is matched

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, if you're being forced to write for IE6, then I would avoid trying to be excessively clever about it. Do what you need to make it usable.

Options that I'd consider:

1. Split the regex into three separate queries. No more need for look-ahead. It will be slower and messier, and I know you'd rather code it properly, but these are the sacrifices we make if we want to support IE6. It will work, and it shouldn't make any noticeable difference to the user.
2. Forget about trying to do it in Javascript, and simply validate it on the server-side. Given that this is clearly a site for internal use only (no-one in their right mind would be writing a site for external use with IE6 support), you can probably get away with dropping niceties like a responsive UI, especially for fringe features like password management.

Finally, please please stress to your company that IE6 is obsolete. Microsoft will cease all support for it in early 2014: at this time, any security issues that are found (and there will be many of them) will go unfixed. And for that reason, you can be sure that they will be aggressively targeted by malware: having IE6 in your network will become a security nightmare that you cannot begin to imagine. You have a year to upgrade. If you haven't started planning for it now, you are highly likely to miss the target, and you **will** get hacked.

Assuming your company has some modicum of sense, and the upgrade does happen, it's worth bearing in mind that any IE6-specific code you write now only has a limited shelf life. So I'll repeat what I said at the start: do what you need to make it *usable* for IE6 users; but don't put too much effort into making it *good* for them.

Answer (score -1):

you have wrong regex, use this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}$
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but that looks identical to the regex in the question?

Comment: origin regex was not identical, but you edit and replace origin

Comment: @Spudley simply indented the code as it should be, it was the same regex but 2 of the asterisks weren't showing as they were being interpreted as italic tags outside of the code block.

Comment: Not so: I merely added padding so that it is formatted correctly in the site. The actual regex code is the same as it was all along.

Comment: in this case are identical =)

Comment: Nevertheless, the question states that he can't use look-ahead regex, so he needs an answer that doesn't include it.

Comment: in this case use 4 regex one by one `\d`, `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `.{8,20}` if all success that password is ok, otherwise impossible